# AttributeError: module 'users.models' has no attribute 'User' (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have done this to make friend System by Django:

users/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from friends import models as friends_models


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User Model Definition"""

    LANGUAGE_KOREAN = 'kr'
    LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = 'en'

    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = ((LANGUAGE_KOREAN, "한국어"), (LANGUAGE_ENGLISH, "영어"))

    CURRENCY_USA = "en"
    CURRENCY_KOREA = "kr"
    CURRENCY_EUROPE = "eu"

    CURRENCY_CHOICES = ((CURRENCY_KOREA, "KRW"),
                        (CURRENCY_USA, "USD"), (CURRENCY_EUROPE, "EUR"))

    friends = models.ManyToManyField(friends_models.Friends, blank=True)

    # optional information
    language = models.CharField(
        choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, max_length=2, blank=True, default=LANGUAGE_KOREAN)
    currency = models.CharField(
        choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES, max_length=2, blank=True, default=CURRENCY_KOREA)
    birthdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

friends/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from cores import models as core_models
from users import models as user_models


class RequestFriends(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Friends(core_models.TimeStampedModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    friends = models.ForeignKey(
        user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

when i try to makemigrations or migrate, error appear like

> File "/Users/kimdoehoon/Project/web_dev/divideN/friends/models.py",
>   line 8, in RequestFriends
>       user_from = models.ForeignKey(user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) AttributeError: module 'users.models' has no
>   attribute 'User'

I already have User model, but why users.models has no attribute User?
What it means?

Comment: Not related, but why are you trying to implement your own User model? The default does not suit you?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just try to stuyding.

Comment: I assume you need one-to-one relation to the default User implementation.

Comment: there is a circular dependency in your models, first try to remove that, like your User model need Friend Model which is in friends app but in friends app RequestFriends model need User model

Comment: add related_name and then try

Comment: models.ForeignKey(user_models.User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='foo')